# Apache Camel invoke SOAP service

Tags: soap, apache-camel, redhat

I am new in Apache Camel and I use Red Hat CodeReady Studio 12.16.0.GA.
I want invoke soap web service.
I have used this example https://tomd.xyz/camel-consume-soap-service/

This is my camel context file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:camel-cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring       https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPInInterceptor" id="gZipInInterceptor"/>
    <bean
        class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPOutInterceptor" id="gZipOutInterceptor"/>
    <camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint
        address="http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso"
        id="fullCountryInfoResponseClient" serviceClass="org.oorsprong.websamples_countryinfo.CountryInfoServiceSoapType">
        <camel-cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="gZipInInterceptor"/>
        </camel-cxf:inInterceptors>
        <camel-cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="gZipOutInterceptor"/>
        </camel-cxf:outInterceptors>
    </camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="bean-66d2672d-c6c0-4984-bc31-90bc30bfaaef"/>
    <camelContext id="camel"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:order="http://fabric8.com/examples/order/v7">
        <route id="simple-route">
            <from id="_to2" uri="timer:timerName?delay=0&amp;repeatCount=1"/>
            <setBody id="_setBody2">
                <constant id="id">"US"</constant>
            </setBody>
            <bean beanType="GetFullCountryInfoBuilder.class" id="_bean1" method="getFullCountryInfo"/>
            <setHeader headerName="operationNamespace" id="_setHeader1">
                <constant>http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="operationName" id="_setHeader2">
                <constant>FullCountryInfo</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to id="_to1" uri="cxf:bean:fullCountryInfoResponseClient"/>
            <setBody id="_setBody1">
                <simple>${body}</simple>
            </setBody>
            <log id="_log1" message=">>>${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

this is my input bean

```
import org.oorsprong.websamples.FullCountryInfo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GetFullCountryInfoBuilder {
    
    public GetFullCountryInfoBuilder() {}

    @Value("${id}")
    private java.lang.String id;
    @Bean
    public FullCountryInfo getFullCountryInfo(java.lang.String id) {
        FullCountryInfo request = new FullCountryInfo();
        request.setSCountryISOCode(id);

        return request;
    }
}
```

There is lot of problems around it. First I cannot pass input parameter into body.
I tried to set body like this

```
      <web:FullCountryInfo xmlns:web="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
         <web:sCountryISOCode>US</web:sCountryISOCode>
      </web:FullCountryInfo>
```

but got no response or just logged nothing.
I have tried to use bean to create request but I get

```
InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'getFullCountryInfoBuilder': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'id' in value "${id}"
```

When I replace placeholder with constant

```
InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'getFullCountryInfo' defined in class path resource [com/example/GetFullCountryInfoBuilder.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'getFullCountryInfo' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

or when I remove input parameter from method getFullCountryInfo Camel cannot found GetFullCountryInfoBuilder class

```
InvocationTargetException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route simple-route at: >>> Bean[GetFullCountryInfoBuilder.class] <<< in route: Route(simple-route)[[From[timer:timerName?delay=0&repeatCoun... because of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GetFullCountryInfoBuilder.class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two errors are in the field of passing a parameter to a bean method.

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'id' in value "${id}"
```

The expression `@Value("${id}")` references a Spring property named `id` but it does not exist. Since you define a route step with this ID, I suspect that you want to pass the value "US" that you set as message body to the method.

The [Spring annotation `@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) has **no idea about your Camel route** so this does not work.

However you can use [Camel annotations](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/parameter-binding-annotations.html) to tell Camel to inject the message body you set to "US" as argument `id` in your method.

```
getFullCountryInfo(@Body String id) {
```

You could also set the value into a message header with `setHeader` and use the annotation `@Header` to inject it into a method. Because when you have an input message (not a timer) you usually don't want to override the body.

The other problem is that the bean cannot be resolved, even when you remove the parameter and set the body static.

```
ClassNotFoundException: GetFullCountryInfoBuilder.class
```

I guess this is because the `beanType` should be defined like this

```
org.oorsprong.websamples.GetFullCountryInfoBuilder // i guessed the package name
```

So it must be the full package/classname but without the ".class" suffix.

Comment: Thank you. It helps a lot. Now all problem with bean disappeared.
But there is problem with converting response into String because of Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-1599152842117-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-1599152842117-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.oorsprong.websamples.FullCountryInfo cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Do you try to convert the response to a String anywhere? Perhaps because you do something like `String response = myFullCountryInfo // object myFullCountryInfo cannot be cast to String`

Comment: Yes, I have tried. After cxf:bean:fullCountryInfoResponseClient I put `<bean beanType="sk.interway.GetFullCountryInfoBuilder" id="_bean2" method="getFullCountryInfoOutput"/>` which use method `@Bean
    public String getFullCountryInfoOutput(@Body FullCountryInfoResponse response) {
     String ret = response.getFullCountryInfoResult().getSName() + " - " + response.getFullCountryInfoResult().getSCapitalCity() + " - " + response.getFullCountryInfoResult().getSCurrencyISOCode();
        return ret;
    }`

Comment: But it looks like request object FullCountryInfo is casted to String. I don't know why or where.

Comment: It looks like CXF don't handle FullCountryInfo object but String and Camel tries to convert it.   
When I change return value of getFullCountryInfo to String this exception disappear.

Comment: I have removed Bean1 with getFullCountryInfo and sed body to "US" and I have added Bean2 `<bean beanType="com.example.GetFullCountryInfoBuilder" id="_bean2" method="getFullCountryInfoOutput"/>` which converts output into String. This leads to right result in the log.

Comment: I am sorry, but there is too much comment code to merge mentally with your question :-) I would suggest you create a new well described question for the new problem with your current route and beans, logs etc